# how to make next input question repeat a number of times based on user input from previous function

Tags: python

I've written this code because I wanted the function to only proceed to the next one if the user has made an input between 1 and 5:

```
def max_pizza(question):

  error = "Please enter a number between 1 and 5."

  valid = False

  while not valid:

    try:
      response=int(input(question))
      if  1<= response <=5:
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
        return response
    
      else:
        print(error)
   
    except ValueError:
      print(error)
```

It's just I needed help with how to make a function to repeat question based on input from the last function, as everytime I seemed to try to type in code and run it, it says that function object can't be interpreted as integer, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: How are you calling `max_pizza`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? it seems to work fine

Comment: _I wanted the function to only proceed to the next one_ What exactly does "proceed to the next one" mean?  Do you mean another call to `max_pizza()`?  Or a call to another function?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Just an assumption, since you're asking a number as input: `range(max_pizza)` (i.e. without calling the function) will raise the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see in the example where you call the function `max_pizza`. At the end of the code, if you haven't done this already, add `max_pizza("Anything")`.

Second, it works just fine for me (using `Python 3.8.6`). Try to update your Python installation to the latest version. I'm not sure if something is changed to `input` or `int`, but these two things are the only differences for now.

Third, maybe you're calling this function somewhere, then you should post that one too, and the exact error message.